# Break the loop if condition is met in another loop SCRAPY

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a `SCRAPY SPIDER` where I send requests to an `API`. I need to check if a condition is met, I need to break the loop.

I have the loop in the `parse` method and content and `parse_api` method. I tried to use the following logic but it didn't work.

```py
if 'date container' not in self.html:
    break
```

I get the following exception `AttributeError: 'SpiderClass' object has no attribute 'html'`

What could be the possible logic to handle this exception?

Below is my code:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import json


class SpiderClass(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_name'

    custom_settings = {
        "FEED_FORMAT": 'csv',
        "FEED_URI": 'dataset.csv'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        links_list = ['https://10times.com/company/informa-knect']
        for link in links_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse)

    
    def parse(self, response):
        ids = response.xpath('//input[@id="companyId"]/@value').get()
        company_name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()

        main_data = {
            "Links": response.url,
            "CompanyName": company_name,
        }

        # sending request for upcoming event api
        off_set = 1
        while True:
            if 'date-container' not in self.html:
                break

            off_set_number = off_set * 5
            api_url = f'https://10times.com/ajax?for=companyEvents&id={ids}&by=&offset={off_set_number}&pastHit=0&calValue=upcoming'

            yield response.follow(url=api_url, meta=main_data,callback=self.parse_api)

            off_set += 1


    def parse_api(self, response):
        api_json = json.loads(response.body)
        self.html = api_json['html']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(SpiderClass)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

### **EDIT**

So, there's some other issues in your code. You use the value `ids` but this is not defined anywhere. You need to generate this somehow.

Also, there needs to be an initial `yield` before the `while` statement. My bad for not catching this one. The thing is, without the initial `yield` the evaluation of `hasattr(self, 'html')` will always be `False`.

### **ADJUSTED CODE**

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        company_name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()

        main_data = {
            "Links": response.url,
            "CompanyName": company_name,
        }

        # sending request for upcoming event api
        off_set = 1
        api_url = f'https://10times.com/ajax?for=companyEvents&id={ids}&by=&offset={off_set * 5}&pastHit=0&calValue=upcoming'
        yield response.follow(url=api_url, meta=main_data,callback=self.parse_api)

        while hasattr(self, 'html') and 'date-container' in self.html:

            off_set_number = off_set * 5
            api_url = f'https://10times.com/ajax?for=companyEvents&id={ids}&by=&offset={off_set_number}&pastHit=0&calValue=upcoming'

            yield response.follow(url=api_url, meta=main_data,callback=self.parse_api)

            off_set += 1
```

### **ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Two things, using `while True` followed by an `if` statement is absolutely not the way to go. A `while` statement is already an evaluation statement. [See w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp).

Secondly, the [standard function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_hasattr.asp) `hasattr()` will check if an object has the listed attribute. If not, it will return `False` and the second part of the evaluation is not performed.

### **adjusted parse() function**

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        company_name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()

        main_data = {
            "Links": response.url,
            "CompanyName": company_name,
        }

        # sending request for upcoming event api
        off_set = 1
        # the while statement already does an if.
        while hasattr(self, 'html') and 'date-container' in self.html:

            off_set_number = off_set * 5
            api_url = f'https://10times.com/ajax?for=companyEvents&id={ids}&by=&offset={off_set_number}&pastHit=0&calValue=upcoming'

            yield response.follow(url=api_url, meta=main_data,callback=self.parse_api)

            off_set += 1
```

Comment: It returns an empty list only. I have a question as well. Where this 'html' parameter comes from in the hasattr function?

Comment: from the `self.html` you provided. It's the string representation of the attribute name.

Comment: All right, but it gives me an empty list [] only. When I print print(self.html) in the parse_api method, it returns an empty list

Comment: I guess it doesn't go to the parse_api method and breaks.

Comment: Oops. I didn't read the code well enough. I edited my answer, explanation included...

Comment: Sorry, my bad about the ids, it's there I just edited my question. It seems like, it only requests ones to the API and the breaks. It doesn't increase the off_set value and requests to the next page.